# Redirection from www.example.com to www.example.com/index.jsp

Tags: redirect, apache2, tomcat7

I have setup apache2 and tomcat7 on ubuntu 14.04.

my domain name is www.example.com , which I want to redirect to the www.example.com/index.jsp on to the tomcat as this is the login page. How can this be done? The set up works fine for  a request made to www.example.com/index.jsp. The apache virtualHost setting is

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

the redirection in my understanding should happen on the apache. As the apache is acting just as a proxy and not serving any requests by itself can we use the  directive ? Where and how to make the change. Any pointers appreciated

I tried rewriting the url in  the virtualHost but it doesn't seem to be working

```
ServerName www.example.com <br>
RewriteEngine On <br>
RewriteRule ^http://www\.example\.com$ https://www.example.com/index.jsp [R]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rewrite rule

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^/$ /index.jsp [R]
```

It basically will search that if, the uri path starts  and ends with a `/` it will redirect it to /index.jsp , this should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you!! That solved the issue and boy wasn't it simple!! :)